# Get most commonly visited second page for a given page

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm curious to know if it is possible to be able to get the most visited second page for a specific page URL.

For example, from *Page A*, can I use the Google Analytics (GA) API to find get the most frequently visited page which visitors navigate towards next?

In other words, I would like to use GA API to tell me that 60% of users navigate towards *Page B* immediately after *Page A*. And if a user is on *Page C*, they have the greatest chance of visiting *Page D* next.

I am using the PHP library:

```
$analytics->data_ga->get(
   'ga:' . $profileId,
   '30daysAgo',
   'today',
   'ga:secondPagePath',
    array(
      'filters' => 'ga:pageTitle%3D%3Dabout-us'
    )
);
```

In the above example I am trying to find the most popular second page from the "about-us" URL. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to find relevant metrics and dimensions is to use this:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

[image]

**You need to bear in mind the dimension scope**: so I think you should read the below page:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

**Now to your question**: `ga:pageTitle` is a hit-level dimension (tracked for each page), whereas `ga:secondPagePath` is session-level dimension collected only once per session, see description given in explorer, **thus the query you're trying to run won't work**.

> ga:secondPagePath: The second page in users' sessions.

**Also, you cannot query a previous/next page combination using `ga:pageTitle`** since the filtering is done on the previous page (see below) for which there is no dimension available.

Instead **you should query on `ga:pagePath` (= next page) with filter on `ga:previousPagePath` (= previous page).**

To save time, use the query explorer and port your queries to PHP once you have them working:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: Thanks for that. Just to make sure I have this right, the returned data would contain a list of page URL's (ga:pathPath), each with a page count?

Comment: Yes, although "page count" per se doesn't exist in GA, you would use `ga:pageviews` or `ga:uniquePageviews`